# STM microcontroller: Is there a way to reset and reprogram read-only memory?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, bootloader, non-volatile-memory

I have an STM32F427VIT6 embedded microcontroler. It has a protected-memory bootloader.

Is there a way to reset it and modify that bootloader?

Comment: please read the datasheet ... `is there a way?` is not a very useful question, because the answer is almost always the same, `yes`

Comment: Do you mean the factory bootloader, or some custom bootloader?

Comment: @Justme It is a custom bootloader (Trezor hardware wallet). They call it a boardloader. I am trying to modify it to add custom functionality without it constantly warning about invalid checksum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a custom bootloader, you need to work with what it enables you to do. If it does not allow disabling protections or allow accessing the factory bootloader via hardware straps or JTAG/SWD, then there is no way. It will likely disable debug interfaces and bootloader access but since you seem to be able to modify it already, so you should also have some understanding what it does or how it works.